# What should I do in Mathematica to Factorize (x^4 + 324)

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, factorization

I am unable to factorize (x^4 + 324). It should be very easy but it is not clicking me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why that should be very easy? It does not seems to be an algebraic formula, and factorization is an NP-full problem

Comment: This is off-topic.  Neither the question nor the answers posted so far show any indications of being programming related.

Comment: Factor[x^4 + 324, Extension -> I]

Comment: There's a Mathematica specific StackExchange site (mathematica.stackexchange.com) if you are interested

Answer (score 4):

You are right, it is very simple: [Factor[x^4 + 324]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Factor%5Bx%5E4%20%2b%20324%5D)

> x^4 + 324 = (x^2 - 6x + 18)(x^2 + 6x + 18)

Comment: You can go further as shown in the link you provided

Comment: Sure, but you have exit the integers and the reals, and the question specified no domain.

Comment: `(a²-b²) = (a+b)(a-b)` and  `√i = (√2/2) + (√2/2)i (and negative too)` - btw, I didn't touch maths for ages...

Comment: My point is, x^2 ± 6x + 18 are irreducible in ℤ[x], ℚ[x] and ℝ[x]. If the OP was interested in factorization in some other ring it should have been specified in the question.

Comment: It's easiest to see this as `x^4+324 = x^4 + 36x^2 + 324 - 36x^2 = (x^2+18)^2 - 36x^2` and then factoring it as a difference of two perfect squares: `((x^2+18)-6x)((x^2+18)+6x)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's a difference of two squares if you're factoring over the complex numbers:

(x^2 - 18i)(x^2 + 18i)

As Joni pointed out in another answer, it actually **is** possible to factor this over the real numbers as well. I'm sure that is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: ?! https://www.google.com/search?q=sqrt%28i%29